# Is $\Bbb C^n$ pathwise connected?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am currently very new to Algebraic Geometry and I was thinking whether the complex affine space i.e. $\Bbb C^n$ is pathwise connected or not.

Kindly provide some argument.Thanks in advance for helping....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, take the segment between two points, it is a path.